# How to get size/length of member/user guilds/servers?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Discord.js 13.7.0 | Node.js 16.5.5

Hi all, could I somehow get information on how many servers/guilds someone has?

I want this information to be added to the command `userinfo`

Example from dyno dashboard https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kkJP.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only able to get the amount of servers your bot client is in.

To get the amount another user is in you need to use Discord's OAuth2 with the `guilds` permission. [Documentation here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2). This is not possible with Discord.js in any of the documentation. You can check the [User docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) if you would like.

If you are creating a dashboard like the image provided, just have your guests log in and require `guilds` in the permissions scope. Try going here: `https://discord.com/developers/applications/<your application ID>/oauth2/url-generator` and then check the documentation for the methods to display on your website.